# Can not remove applications

Tags: software-center

I have a fresh Ubuntu 16 installed. I'm trying to remove some preinstalled applications, such as thundermail, to free up some space (I have a space issue). I thought the applications had been removed successfully, but I discovered that all of them are still there, so I removed again then closed the software and update center then reopened it again, and the application I tried to remove aren't removed.

How can I solve this?

Sorry for my poor English :)

Edit:

This is the output of the command sudo apt-get purge thunderbird:

```
The following packages were automatically installed and are no longer required:
  libexo-1-0 libexo-common libexo-helpers libunique-1.0-0 libxfce4ui-1-0
  libxfce4ui-common libxfce4util-bin libxfce4util-common libxfce4util7
  libxfconf-0-2 linux-headers-4.15.0-45 linux-headers-4.15.0-45-generic
  linux-image-4.15.0-45-generic linux-modules-4.15.0-45-generic
  linux-modules-extra-4.15.0-45-generic linux-modules-extra-4.15.0-66-generic
  xfconf
Use 'sudo apt autoremove' to remove them.
The following packages will be REMOVED:
  thunderbird*
0 upgraded, 0 newly installed, 1 to remove and 94 not upgraded.
After this operation, 0 B of additional disk space will be used.
Do you want to continue? [Y/n] y
(Reading database ... 310378 files and directories currently installed.)
Removing thunderbird (1:60.9.0+build1-0ubuntu0.16.04.2) ...
Purging configuration files for thunderbird (1:60.9.0+build1-0ubuntu0.16.04.2) ...
```

Comment: You can try `sudo apt-get purge thunderbird`, and post the output of there are errors.

Comment: Removing a few apps you don't want will free some space, but not that much.  It might be better to try to install the minimal ubuntu ISO and then just install what you want.

Comment: @mikewhatever, I made an edit

Comment: Looks like it worked. Now run `sudo apt-get autoremove --purge` to remove leftover dependencies and unused kernels. That should free even more space.